# Filtering characters during marshal() operation of Marshaller class in Java

Tags: java, marshalling

I am trying to serialize a **POJO** to an **XML** using the **Marshaller** class in Java. Is there some way to remove some known characters *(*,+,-)* during this *marshal()* operation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way with a JAXB Adapter if the characters to remove are for String instances.
If it's for another classes, the general logic presented here stays the same.

Adapter Class :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;


public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
          return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
       return string.replaceAll("[*+-]", "");
    }

}
```

Then configure your XmlAdapter in order that it is used during marshaling.
You can do in the jaxb binding file (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)  if you want generalize it for all pojo classes using Jaxb or you can apply directly the adapter in the target pojo classes via Annotation on the String field :

```
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = StringAdapter.class)
  private String string;
```